# Floating DIV Containers

Tags: css, html, css-float

Am actually creating a News Container and within it news content with heading, images(if any), summary and eventually a read more link.

The news content is placed in a DIV with a fixed width but i dont want a fixed height however.

The issue is that i want the containers to float on the left, which works but since the height are not the same am getting a white space between the 3rd and 4th one.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you no need to specify height.the height will be automatically adjusted based on the content size.

```
<div id="news-content"></div>
```

css

```
#news-content
{
width:100%;
float:left;
}
```